# AlertDialog not working when populating with layout that has a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, bluetooth

I am trying to display an alert dialog of a layout with a listview in it and am running into an exception in my catch.  This listview is populated in the myReceiver method that populates the arraylist that is displayed in the listview.

Here is the method:(This is the catch that is emailing me the stacktrace)

```
private void startSearching() {
        Log.i("Log", "in the start searching method");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        BluetoothDemo.this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.found_devices, (RelativeLayout) getCurrentFocus());
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setView(dialoglayout);

            Button closeBtn = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
            closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBluetooth();
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
            sendEmail(stackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Here is the myReceiver method:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String toastText = "Discovered: " + device.getName();
                Toast.makeText(context, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try
                {
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput", boolean.class).invoke(device);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Log", "Inside the exception: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(arrayListBluetoothDevices.size()<1) // this checks if the size of bluetooth device is 0,then add the
                {                                           // device to the arraylist.

                    detectedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    //detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    boolean flag = true;    // flag to indicate that particular device is already in the arlist or not
                    for(int i = 0; i<arrayListBluetoothDevices.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(device.getAddress().equals(arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(i).getAddress()))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag == true)
                    {
                        detectedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                        arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at my.obd2connector.BluetoothDemo.startSearching(BluetoothDemo.java:372)
at my.obd2connector.BluetoothDemo.access$200(BluetoothDemo.java:56)
at my.obd2connector.BluetoothDemo$ButtonClicked.onClick(BluetoothDemo.java:301)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Also I am building the same kind of alert dialog in another method with no listview and it works fine.

Comment: can you tell me what is the code @ BluetoothDemo.java:372

Comment: Make sure your `closeBtn` resides inside `R.layout.found_devices` layout file. And also your have initialized your `bluetoothAdapter` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you don't have a button in your found_devices.xml layout with the id close_btn and are therefore getting a null closeBtn.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityClassName.this);
```